# Visualising recursion in C

Tags: c, recursion, printing

I am trying to understand how recursion works in the factorial function. What should I print, so that I can see what actually happens during each recursion call? 
Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


long factorial(long number) {
  if(number <= 1) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return number * factorial(number - 1);
  }
}

int main() {
  int i;

  for(i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    printf("%2d ! = %ld\n", i, factorial(i));
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to print something before the `return 1`.  You'll need to capture the result of `factorial(number - 1)` in a variable, print that, number, and the product before returning the product.  Wouldn't that tell you what you need to know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


long factorial (int level, long number){
    int result;
    printf("[%03d] Calculating: %d\n", level, number);

    if(number <= 1)
    {
        result = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        result = number * factorial(level+1, number - 1);
    }

    printf("[%03d] Returning:   %d\n", level, result);
    return result;
}
int main(){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        printf("%2d ! = %ld\n", i, factorial(0, i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

gives this output

```
[000] Calculating: 10
[001] Calculating: 9
[002] Calculating: 8
[003] Calculating: 7
[004] Calculating: 6
[005] Calculating: 5
[006] Calculating: 4
[007] Calculating: 3
[008] Calculating: 2
[009] Calculating: 1
[009] Returning:   1
[008] Returning:   2
[007] Returning:   6
[006] Returning:   24
[005] Returning:   120
[004] Returning:   720
[003] Returning:   5040
[002] Returning:   40320
[001] Returning:   362880
[000] Returning:   3628800
10 ! = 3628800
```

Where [XXX] is the current level of recursion.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
long factorial (long number){
if(number <= 1){
    return 1;
}else{
    return number * factorial(number - 1);

}
}
```

Assume we pass 4 as first parameter, then function evaluates to:

```
long factorial (long number /*==4*/){
if(4 <= 1){//false
    return 1;
}else{
    return 4 * factorial(4 - 1);

}
}
```

Note return in else can't finish, because it calls another function - factorial (4-1).
So 4 must be multiplied by the result of factorial (3). So it goes and executes factorial(3).

Now we get

```
long factorial (long number /*==3*/){
if(3 <= 1){//false
    return 1;
}else{
    return 3 * factorial(3 - 1);

}

}
```

But again the return here can't finish, since it calls factorial for 3-1=2.

Now one needs to evaluate factorial (2), result of which will be multiplied by 3 and passed to previous return. Again:

```
long factorial (long number /*==2*/){
if(2 <= 1){//false
    return 1;
}else{
    return 2 * factorial(2 - 1);

}
```

}

We have similar problem. But now when executing factorial (2-1) the function will immediately return 1, hence above line will return 2.

This result will be plugged to the result of previous return, giving 2*3; this result -  6 - will be plugged in previous return and yield 6*4, which is the final result 24.

Answer (score 2):

For something ridiculous, factor out the body of `factorial`:

```
long factorial_body(long number) {
  if(number <= 1) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return number * factorial(number - 1);
  }
}
```

Then, rewrite `factorial` to call `factorial_body`, printing some stuff around the call.

```
long factorial (long number) {
    static char output[4096];
    static int level;
    static int index;
    int saved_index;
    long result;
    switch (level++) {
    case 1:  index += snprintf(output + index, sizeof(output) - index, "= ");
    default: index += snprintf(output + index, sizeof(output) - index,
                               "%ld x ", number + 1);
    case 0:  snprintf(output + index, sizeof(output) - index,
                      "factorial(%ld)\n", number);
    }
    saved_index = index;
    printf("%s", output);
    result = factorial_body(number);
    index = saved_index;
    snprintf(output + index, sizeof(output) - index,
             --level ? "%ld\n" : "= %ld\n", result);
    printf("%s", output);
    return result;
}
```

`factorial(10)` will generate the following output:

```
factorial(10)
= 10 x factorial(9)
= 10 x 9 x factorial(8)
= 10 x 9 x 8 x factorial(7)
= 10 x 9 x 8 x 7 x factorial(6)
= 10 x 9 x 8 x 7 x 6 x factorial(5)
= 10 x 9 x 8 x 7 x 6 x 5 x factorial(4)
= 10 x 9 x 8 x 7 x 6 x 5 x 4 x factorial(3)
= 10 x 9 x 8 x 7 x 6 x 5 x 4 x 3 x factorial(2)
= 10 x 9 x 8 x 7 x 6 x 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x factorial(1)
= 10 x 9 x 8 x 7 x 6 x 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1
= 10 x 9 x 8 x 7 x 6 x 5 x 4 x 3 x 2
= 10 x 9 x 8 x 7 x 6 x 5 x 4 x 6
= 10 x 9 x 8 x 7 x 6 x 5 x 24
= 10 x 9 x 8 x 7 x 6 x 120
= 10 x 9 x 8 x 7 x 720
= 10 x 9 x 8 x 5040
= 10 x 9 x 40320
= 10 x 362880
= 3628800
```

I am dubious if the above output will help enhance your understanding of recursion. But, working to understand how the printing code works probably would lead to a better understanding of recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of print statements add whatever you would print to an array or something and then print them out in the order that they were inserted (fifo) after the recursive function is finished.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you a trace of the execution of *factorial*, with indentation:

```
long factorial(long number, int depth){
    printf("%*s enter, number = %d\n", 4*depth, "", number);
    long result = 1;
    if (number > 1) result = number * factorial(number-1, depth+1);
    printf("%*s exit,  result = %d\n", 4*depth, "", result);
    return result;
}
```